# how to deal with temporal overlap and determine the duration ? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

Currently I have successfully coded a program that allows me to find full or partial time overlaps (see 'group_overl' with the same number).

Two cases arise:

- If I have a complete overlap, I must delete the one or those who are included in the first.
- If I have a partial overlap, I must the begin of the second and recalculate the duration.

For better understanding, here is an example:

My df:

```
      alias          begin                      end                         duration    group_overl
0     M4            2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716  2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268  156.218     1
1     M4            2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327  2019-10-21 07:42:02.222821  118.987     1
2     M4            2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657  2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114  27.534      2
3     M4            2019-10-21 07:44:09.936458  2019-10-21 07:44:37.143862  27.207      3
4     M4            2019-10-21 07:45:27.488518  2019-10-21 07:45:54.122312  26.634      4
5     M4            2019-10-21 07:57:27.564887  2019-10-21 08:26:00.413448  1712.849    11
6     M4            2019-10-21 07:58:06.209659  2019-10-21 08:27:00.413448  1734.204    11
```

The expected result:

```
      alias         begin                       end                         duration    
0     M4            2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716  2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268  156.218     

2     M4            2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657  2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114  27.534      
3     M4            2019-10-21 07:44:09.936458  2019-10-21 07:44:37.143862  27.207      
4     M4            2019-10-21 07:45:27.488518  2019-10-21 07:45:54.122312  26.634      
5     M4            2019-10-21 07:57:27.564887  2019-10-21 08:26:00.413448  1712.849    
6     M4            2019-10-21 08:26:00.413448  2019-10-21 08:27:00.413448  60
```

- As you can see row 1 has disappeared because it is completely in the time of row 0. the row 1 has been deleted.
- Row 6 is partially in row 5. So the real begin of 6 is the end of 5. So we make the new difference between the begin and the end of line 6 to have the new duration (here 60s).

I tried several treatments but I can't do it, thanks for your time !

Comment: Are there multiple `alias` values that you need to groupby OR is that column all `M4`?

Comment: in this case all columns are with 'M4' because I already decomposed the df. But in a another project, effectively the groupby is welcome.

Comment: Do you expect more than 2 rows in a `group_overl` group?

Comment: @QuangHoang yeah it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are using `shift()`, this method assumes you have sorted the dataframe by the `begin` column as shown in your example.  It sounds like you don't need to groupby `alias`:

Create the two conditions you have mentioned using `shift`. For the first condition, filter out the results. For the second, use `where()`.

```
df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
c1 = (df['begin'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()) 
     & df['end'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()))
c2 = (df['begin'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()) 
     & df['end'].gt(df['end'].shift()))
df = df[~c1]
df['duration'] = df['duration'].where(~c2, (df['end'] - df['end'].shift()).dt.seconds)
df
Out[1]: 
  alias                      begin                        end  duration  \
0    M4 2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716 2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268   156.218   
2    M4 2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657 2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114    27.534   
3    M4 2019-10-21 07:44:09.936458 2019-10-21 07:44:37.143862    27.207   
4    M4 2019-10-21 07:45:27.488518 2019-10-21 07:45:54.122312    26.634   
5    M4 2019-10-21 07:57:27.564887 2019-10-21 08:26:00.413448  1712.849   
6    M4 2019-10-21 07:58:06.209659 2019-10-21 08:27:00.413448    60.000   

   group_overl  
0            1  
2            2  
3            3  
4            4  
5           11  
6           11
```

If you would like to make sure these conditions, hold by group, then you can create a third condition that they must be in the same group. Make sure you do

`df = df.sort_values(['alias','begin','end])` and then:

```
df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
c1 = (df['begin'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()) 
     & df['end'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()))
c2 = (df['begin'].between(df['begin'].shift(), df['end'].shift()) 
     & df['end'].gt(df['end'].shift()))
c3 = df['alias'] == df['alias'].shift()
df = df[~(c1 & c3)]
df['duration'] = df['duration'].where(~(c2 & c3), (df['end'] - df['end'].shift()).dt.seconds)
df
Out[2]: 
  alias                      begin                        end  duration  \
0    M4 2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716 2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268   156.218   
2    M4 2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657 2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114    27.534   
3    M4 2019-10-21 07:44:09.936458 2019-10-21 07:44:37.143862    27.207   
4    M4 2019-10-21 07:45:27.488518 2019-10-21 07:45:54.122312    26.634   
5    M4 2019-10-21 07:57:27.564887 2019-10-21 08:26:00.413448  1712.849   
6    M4 2019-10-21 07:58:06.209659 2019-10-21 08:27:00.413448    60.000   

   group_overl  
0            1  
2            2  
3            3  
4            4  
5           11  
6           11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And if I need to use `groupby` for some reasons like multi alias (by curuosity) ?

Comment: If a I have another column for `groupby`. With your code, I just need to add it in `sort_values`     c4 = df['priority'] == df['priority'].shift()    df=df[~(c1 & c3 & c4)]     and modify the condition in the `where` ?

Comment: @ThonyNadir exactly. You’ve got it! If you could kindly accept as solution / upvote the answer, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: the where condition is equal to c2 &c3 &c4 ?